# How to handle jquery events for currently hidden elements

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to perform two operations -
1. Hide/display of forms based on which button has clicked
2. defining a click event (with ajax) for submit buttons in each form.

Before I wrote part 2., part 1 was working fine. As soon as I added code of part 2, the part 1 is also not working.

Html code -

```
 <div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="btn1">Button1</button>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary active" id="btn2">Button2</button>
```

```
<!-- Main Form -->

    <form id="login-form" class="form-signin" style="display:inline-block">
         {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="login-wrap">
                <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name..." name="fname" value="">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name..." name="lname" value="">
                 <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="emailaddr" value="">
                <label class="checkbox">
                  I agree to the Terms of Service and Privacy Policy
                </label>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" id="form1btn">Submit</button>
                </div>


        </div>

    </form>
    <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="#" id="ownerform" style="display:none">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="login-wrap">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ownerName" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name" autofocus="">
                <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" autofocus="">-->
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="ownerEmail" name="Email" placeholder="Email" autofocus="">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ownerCompany" name="Company" placeholder="Company" autofocus="">
                <label class="checkbox">
                  I agree to the Terms of Service and Privacy Policy
                </label>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" type="submit" id="form2btn">Submit</button>

            </div>
        </form>
    <div id="formmessage" style="display: none">


    </div>
```

And the corresponding jquery code is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn1').click(function(){
   $('#login-form').css('display','none');
   $('#ownerform').css('display','inline-block');
   ownermethod();
  });

   $('#btn2').click(function(){
   $('#login-form').css('display','inline-block');
   $('#ownerform').css('display','none');


   });

function ownermethod()
{
  $('#form1btn').click(function(){
     var name = $('#ownerName').val();
     var email = $('#ownerEmail').val();
     var company = $('#ownerCompany').val();
     $.ajax({
        url : './request1/',
        type: "POST",
        data : {csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value},
                name: name, email: email; company: company,
                },
        success: function( data ){
            // do something
            //$('#login-form').css('display','inline-block');
             $('#ownerform').css('display','none');
             $('#formmessage').css('display','inline-block');
             $('#formmessage').html(data);

        },
    });

   });
  };

});
```

Am I missing something here? If I omit the custom method. Then part 1 works fine. I believe, this is something to do with hidden elements as when the document is loaded the form1btn is hidden.

Comment: Check for any `browser console errors`...

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your quality up

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move the call to the method `ownermethod()` this outside the click event handler

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#btn1').click(function(){
        $('#login-form').css('display','none');
        $('#ownerform').css('display','inline-block');
     });

   ownermethod(); 

   $('#btn2').click(function(){
       $('#login-form').css('display','inline-block');
       $('#ownerform').css('display','none');       
   });

});

function ownermethod()
{
...
}

</script>
```